# Jquery UI Dialog Empty On Auto-Open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a somewhat strange error with my jquery dialog.

When I have it autoopen, the dialog box is completely empty. If I exit out of the dialog and then reopen (through the standard dialog open event) the content appears.

The jquery setup:

```
$("#content_locker").dialog({
autoOpen: true,
modal: true,
height: 600,
width: 800
});
```

[Here you can see the webpage that I am working on](http://clfls.com/?9) (it is a link-shortening service).

The dialog div starts on line 148 of the source:

```
<div id="content_locker" title="Exclusive Content">
```

You will see that the dialog is empty. If you exit out and click on the unlock button, the proper html is there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the modal is hidden at the beginning due this code on your css:

```
#content_locker{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
#content_locker{
    diaplay: none;
}
```

It should do the trick ;)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice this answer earlier. Seems to be working fine now:)

Answer (score 1):

It depends the order. If you use `autoOpen`, you should fill the html content first, and then init the dialog. (`autoOpen` means once you have initilized the dialog, it will open.)

```
$("#content_locker").html(the_html_content).dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  modal: true,
  height: 600,
  width: 800
});
```

Comment: Okay, so how can I make sure the html is there first?

Comment: @user1019588 That depend on you, you should create the content first before the dialog open. Isn't this source wrote by you?  http://clfls.com/js/dwn.php?id=&x=&s=&sid=&limit=

Comment: Yeah that was written by me, but I purposely took the dialog JS out of there and put it in the index file (simply at the bottom of the page) underneath the html.

Comment: @user1019588 Yes, you need to use `.html()` to fill the content and after that, init the dialog.

Comment: Isn't Dialog supposed to read the html from the div automatically? I added the line alert($("#content_locker").html()); before and it alerts all of the html in the div

Comment: @user1019588 Try check the visibility of the html content.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the HTML is not available yet when you are trying to display the dialog. Did you specify it in the DOM ready event..

Try this

```
  $(function() {
    $("#content_locker").dialog({
       autoOpen: true,
       modal: true,
       height: 600,
       width: 800
    });
  });
```

// If that does not work try showing it explicitly
// by

```
  $("#content_locker").show();
```

Comment: Tried different variations of this, but did not work :/ Thanks for the effort though.